# function does not create image yet image it passed

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, image-resizing, image-uploading

Ok so the problem seems to be in the function not creating the image, or in the script it self which does not pass the image to the function

Here is the upload script (note: this is injected into AJAX)

```
    $path = "cache/";

    $valid_formats = array("jpg", "png", "gif", "jpeg");
    if(isset($_POST) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")
        {
        $name = $_FILES['photoimg']['name'];
        $size = $_FILES['photoimg']['size'];

        if(strlen($name))
                {
                ist($txt, $ext) = explode(".", $name);
                if(in_array($ext,$valid_formats))
                {
                if($size<(2024*2024))
                    {
                    $new_file = "header.".$ext;
                    $tmp = $_FILES['photoimg']['tmp_name'];
                    if(move_uploaded_file($tmp, $path.$new_file))
                    {

            echo "<img src='cache/".$new_file."?".time()."'  class='preview'>";

               createHeader($new_file);                                 
                    }

                    else
                    echo "failed";
                    }

                    else
                    echo "Image file size max 1 MB";                    
                    }
                    else
                echo "Invalid file format..";   
                }

            else
                echo "Please select image..!";

            exit;
        }
```

now here is the function

```
function createHeader($new_file) {

$path = "uploads/";
$image = "cache/";
$width = 800;

    if(preg_match('/[.](jpg)|(jpeg)$/', $new_file)) {  

        $im = imagecreatefromjpeg($image . $new_file); 

    } else if (preg_match('/[.](gif)$/', $new_file)) {  

        $im = imagecreatefromgif($image . $new_file);   
        imagecolortransparent($im, black);      

    } else if (preg_match('/[.](png)$/', $new_file)) {  

        $im = imagecreatefrompng($image . $new_file);   
    }  

    imagealphablending($im, false);
    imagesavealpha($im, true);  

    $ox = imagesx($im);  
    $oy = imagesy($im);  

    $nx = $width;  
    $ny = floor($oy * ($width / $ox) ); 

    imagecopyresampled($nm, $im, 0,0,0,0,$nx,$ny,$ox,$oy);      
    imagealphablending($im, true);  
    if(!file_exists($path)) {  
      if(!mkdir($path)) {  
           die("There was a problem. Please try again!");  
      }  
       }  

    imagejpeg($nm, $path . $new_file, 100);

    imagedestroy($im);
    imagedestroy($nm);

}
```

In logic what the code must do is if a user using my cms is loged-in he or she can change the header on the page by clicking an icon which will make a jQuery call to edit.php passing needed query string. From there own user can upload a new image which will be renamed header.jpg and over-write the original image

The header.jpg has to be uploaded into uploads/ directory and a copy of original image cache/ should be unlinked ones the function can create a copy and put it into uploads/ directory.

What is happening is that the first script is uploading the file and is putting it into cache/ directory but the function does not seem to work and does nothing for uploads/ directory.

Any idea what I may be doing wrong or not doing that is causing this annoying problem?

Comment: does your web server have permissions to write to the directory that you are storing the image in?

Comment: @thenetimp yes it does, this is a very very old function and has been tested on many servers works all the time, it is a slight re-write of what i use in a custom forum software. Its just not working for this project not sure if this may be do to AJAX

Comment: found your problem, look at my answer you're calling the creation of the image after you echo the image tag so the image does not exist at that time.

Comment: @thenetimp nop still does not work, images are uploaded to cache but function does nothing with them so the uploads directory is unchanged and so is the image inside

Comment: `ist($txt, $ext) = explode(".", $name);` should be `list($txt, $ext) = explode(".", $name);`

Comment: @thenetimp it was function problem after all :) i missed out $nm = imagecreatetruecolor($nx, $ny);
    imagealphablending($im, false); so imagecopyresampled($nm, $im, 0,0,0,0,$nx,$ny,$ox,$oy); would not work

Comment: awesome, sometimes you just need to talk it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$path = "cache/";

```
$valid_formats = array("jpg", "png", "gif", "jpeg");
if(isset($_POST) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")
    {
    $name = $_FILES['photoimg']['name'];
    $size = $_FILES['photoimg']['size'];

    if(strlen($name))
            {
            list($txt, $ext) = explode(".", $name);
            if(in_array($ext,$valid_formats))
            {
            if($size<(2024*2024))
                {
                $new_file = "header.".$ext;
                $tmp = $_FILES['photoimg']['tmp_name'];
                if(move_uploaded_file($tmp, $path.$new_file))
                {

           // This needs to happen before the echo of the image tag
           createHeader($new_file);                                 

        echo "<img src='cache/".$new_file."?".time()."'  class='preview'>";
                }

                else
                echo "failed";
                }

                else
                echo "Image file size max 1 MB";                    
                }
                else
            echo "Invalid file format..";   
            }

        else
            echo "Please select image..!";

        exit;
    }
```

Comment: can't even see the function output a message

Comment: doing a test it does work as i am not getting an error yet it looks like the image is not being passed via the createHeader($new_file)